# r loop/function to find matches from a list

Tags: r, list, function, loops

I have a list of sales people in three columns and I want to go down a list I have and:
a) Where their name appears in any of the three column
b) their name appears with a Trainee Sales person (these would be people whose name is not in the list)

```
ilist <- c("SP1","SP2","SP3","SP4","SP5")
    
df2 <- 
    data.frame(sales1 = c("SP5","SP5","SP4","SP3","SP2","SP1","SP3"), 
               sales2 = c("","SP4","SP1","SP1","SP5","SP3",""), 
               sales3 = c("","SP9","","SP6","","",""))
```

Output I'd expect something like below answer(though i'd take any output):

```
      A     B   
SP1   3     1 
SP2   1     0 
SP3   3     1 
SP4   1     1 
SP5   3     1
```

I've tried creating a loop and a function but i cant seem to get them to work.
The aim after getting this to work is to make it part of a `group_by` so I can break it down by type and year

```
data %>%
group_by(type,year) %>%
your helpful answer here
```

edit:
`select` of the columns I'm looking at using.
My iList would be something like the below
(in the 3 Columns column 2 and 3 will contain blanks where  the sales person only appears in column 1; there is also no set placement for where a sales person or trainee may appear)

```
ilist <- c("SJ","KW","MOLC","FERB","BACC")



structure(list(iYear = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 9L), .Label = c("2020-07-01", "2020-07-02", "2020-07-03", 
"2020-07-04", "2020-07-06", "2020-07-07", "2020-07-08", "2020-07-09", 
"2020-07-10", "2020-07-11", "2020-07-12", "2020-07-13", "2020-07-14", 
"2020-07-15", "2020-07-16", "2020-07-17", "2020-07-18", "2020-07-19", 
"2020-07-20", "2020-07-21", "2020-07-22", "2020-07-23", "2020-07-24", 
"2020-07-25", "2020-07-27", "2020-07-28", "2020-07-29", "2020-07-30", 
"2020-07-31"), class = "factor"), iType = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("", "ZB", "BS", 
"CFN", "CTR", "MJ", "UK", "EFH", "ENOC", "EY", "F", "G", "CD", 
"HAEM", "HN", "IC", "LB", "LY", "MNN", "MOS", "NERO", "ZZZ", 
"ZZZQE", "GFT", "PG", "RE", "SK", "UR"), class = "factor"), 
    Sales.1 = structure(c(74L, 20L, 74L, 16L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 58L, 41L), .Label = c("", "ABUE", "AHMEM", 
    "AJOS", "ANNS", "AOK", "BACC", "BH", "BLAFM", "BLOCA", "BRAD", 
    "BROWNJ", "BRT", "BUIH", "BURDA", "BURYA", "CANRJ", "CAVM", 
    "CHAMBA", "COOSNP", "COUPSI", "CPH", "CTT", "DARA", "DILP", 
    "EXPAT", "FCH", "FERB", "FERMA", "GT", "GT", "HAEM", "HAMJR", 
    "HENJ", "HENJA", "HOWRA", "HUSA", "ILINC", "JONG", "KC", 
    "KNOT", "KW", "LAUC", "LOOP", "LYEJO", "LYNN", "MAJJ", "MCGREA", 
    "MENT", "MKB", "MOLC", "MUDHS", "MULLM", "NC", "NODS", 
    "O'BSG", "OLIT", "OLIVK", "PAEI", "PARKD", "PATEF", "PERT", 
    "POL", "PTRHUS", "RAMACN", "RAMS", "REYMA", "ROBCM", "ROBINE", 
    "SAMJN", "SAYC", "SHARMM", "SHEG", "SJ", "SJN", "SKINT", 
    "SLOP", "SORT", "SOUBIO", "SPOE", "TELED", "THAN", "THEL", 
    "TURH", "TURHJ", "UCONS", "UPH", "UT", "VALK", "WALJ"
    ), class = "factor"), Sales.2 = structure(c(1L, 
    12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 45L), .Label = c("", "ABUE", 
    "AHMEM", "AJOS", "AOK", "BACC", "BH", "BLAFM", "BROWNJ", 
    "BUIH", "BURDA", "BURYA", "CANRJ", "CAVM", "CHAMBA", "COOSNP", 
    "COUPSI", "DARA", "DILP", "FCH", "FERB", "FERMA", "GYNT", 
    "HOWRA", "HUSA", "ILINC", "KW", "LAUC", "LOOP", "LYNN", "MAJJ", 
    "MOLC", "MULLM", "NC", "OLIVK", "PARKD", "POL", "PTRHUS", 
    "RAMS", "REYMA", "ROBCM", "ROBINE", "SAMJN", "SHARMM", "SJ", 
    "SJN", "SKINT", "SLOP", "SORT", "SPOE", "TELED", "THAN", 
    "THEL", "TURH", "VALK"), class = "factor"), Sales.3 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "AHMEM", 
    "AOK", "BACC", "BLAFM", "CHAMBA", "COUPSI", "DILP", "FCH", 
    "KW", "LOOP", "MAJJ", "PTRHUS", "RAMS", "ROBCM", "SAMJN", 
    "SHARMM", "SJ", "TELED", "THAN", "VALK"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: what you want is not super clear. for example SP1 appears in position 6 of df2$sales1, and in position 3 and 4 of df2$sales2. so when you state you want where they appear in any of the columns, I would have imagined you wanted the results for SP1 in column A to be (3, 4, 6) . why is the result 3? also you say you want to group on type and year... fine, but you don't have any type and year column so unclear what you trying to achieve.

Comment: hum, you want to know on which rows of `df2` a given sale appears with a trainee?

Comment: Updated with live data

Comment: What is `iType` used for in your live data? Is it ignored in this process? Is that used in "break down by type and year"?

Comment: @Ben the Type is the Department/Section that it belongs to.
So its this Period, for these Sections, by this Person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but thought it might be helpful. With your interest in using `group_by` sounds like you might want a `tidyverse` approach.

Here, would add row numbers, so you can `group_by` each row to see if a trainee is present with a sales person in the same row.

Then, use `pivot_longer` to put into a long format, and remove the empty strings.

When grouping by the row number, you can add an indicator that those people will have appeared with a trainee sales person. It looks to see if the person is not contained in the `ilist`.

Finally, you can `group_by` each sales person, only include those in `ilist` with `filter`, and add up the number of times appeared (assumes only once per row in the initial data), and number of trainee contacts.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>%
  na_if("") %>%
  na.omit %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  mutate(with_trainee = ifelse(any(!value %in% ilist), 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  filter(value %in% ilist) %>%
  summarise(A = n(),
            B = sum(with_trainee))
```

**Output**

```
  value     A     B
  <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 SP1       3     1
2 SP2       1     0
3 SP3       3     1
4 SP4       2     1
5 SP5       3     1
```

**Edit 1:** With your "live data", and grouping results by year from `iYear` and `iType`, you can try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number(),
         iYear = substr(iYear, 1, 4)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(rn, iYear, iType)) %>%
  na_if("") %>%
  na.omit %>%
  group_by(rn, iYear, iType) %>%
  mutate(with_trainee = ifelse(any(!value %in% ilist), 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(value, iYear, iType) %>%
  filter(value %in% ilist) %>%
  summarise(A = n(),
            B = sum(with_trainee))
```

**Edit 2:** Additional detailed explanation:

Row numbers (`rn` via `row_number`) is helpful in this case, as you want to know if sales people are present at the same time (which implies "within the same row"). So, if 2 sales people share the same `rn`, they were present at the same time.

`iYear` is changed to just a year. It uses `substr()` (substring) to take the 1st through 4th character of `iYear` which in XXXX-XX-XX date format is the year.

`pivot_longer` (and its friend, `pivot_wider`) are really powerful to convert from long <-> wide formats of data. In the [`tidyr` package](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html), `pivot_longer` takes all the columns (except for `rn`, `iYear`, and `iType`) and puts into two columns (`name` and `value`). `value` contains the salesperson in a single column now, instead of multiple columns it started with.

`na_if("")` will make the blank strings `""` become `NA` (missing data). The follow up `na.omit` will remove those rows with `NA` then.

The `group_by` with `rn` makes sure you are looking collectively at those sales people who share the same `rn`. I added `iYear` and `iType` so that they will also show up in the final summarized results. Then, `with_trainee` is a new column that will contain whether that sales person is with a trainee or not (after `group_by` using `any` to see if "any row" within the group, sharing the same `rn`, is in the `ilist` vector). If there is, then code as 1, if not, then code as 0.

The next `group_by` is by `value` (or sales person), using `filter` since you will only want results on those who are in `ilist`. (If you wanted everyone, including trainees not in `ilist`, you could leave this line out.)

The final `summarise` works with the `group_by` - with `n()` showing the number of rows of data per `value` (or per sales person), which is the same as number of different `rn` values a sales person may appear in overall. The `sum(with_trainee)` is the total number of times the `with_trainee` was 1 for a given `value` (or sales person).

**Output**

```
  value iYear iType     A     B
  <fct> <chr> <fct> <int> <dbl>
1 SJ    2020  CFN       3     1
```

Comment: I've added some live data if that helps

Comment: Please see edited answer. This takes the year from `iYear`, and groups by the year and `iType`. Is this closer to what you needed?

Comment: That looks like it works and it is amazing.
Massive help.
Looking at what you've created I have miles still to go.
If I'm reading this right you've:
Added ow ID Numbers >
Made the iYear just a year >
(Pivot_longer I will need to research as I've not come across that) >
Not applicable if Blank >
(no.omit I need to research) >
Group by the three types (number, year and type) >
Add in an extra column for values not in my List to id the Trainee; giving them a 1 >
Filter on what is in my List >
Output the data with Number of matches on List and add up the Trainees
Do I have that right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the expected result to be honest since you say you expect `SP2 | 1 | 0` but SP2 did not appear in line 1. the following might do what you want... or not.

```
library(data.table)

sales <- data.table(sale = c("SP1", "SP2", "SP3", "SP4", "SP5"))

sales_group <- 
  data.table(
    sales1 = c("SP5", "SP5", "SP4", "SP3", "SP2", "SP1", "SP3"),
    sales2 = c("", "SP4", "SP1", "SP1", "SP5", "SP3", ""),
    sales3 = c("", "SP9", "", "SP6", "", "", "")
  )

all <- sort(sales_group[, unique(c(sales1, sales2, sales3))])
all <- all[all != ""]
trainees <- all[!all %in% c(sales$sale, "")]

sales_group[, pos := seq(.N)]

sales1 <- merge(sales, sales_group, by.x = "sale", by.y = "sales1")
sales2 <- merge(sales, sales_group, by.x = "sale", by.y = "sales2")
sales3 <- merge(sales, sales_group, by.x = "sale", by.y = "sales3")
setnames(sales1, c("sale", "plusone", "plustwo", "sales_pos"))
setnames(sales2, c("sale", "plusone", "plustwo", "sales_pos"))
setnames(sales3, c("sale", "plusone", "plustwo", "sales_pos"))
sales_visit_by_sale <- rbind(sales1, sales2, sales3)
sales_visit_by_sale[, with_trainee := FALSE]
sales_visit_by_sale[(plusone %in% trainees) | (plustwo %in% trainees), with_trainee := TRUE]
sales_visit_by_sale[(order(sale, sales_pos)), .(sale, sales_pos, with_trainee)]
```

Comment: I've added some live data if that helps